# Turn off tmap legend on an interactive map?

Tags: r, tmap

Does anyone know how to turn off the legend on an interactive tmap map without having to convert it to a leaflet object? `tm_layout(legend.show = FALSE)` works in plot mode but doesn't seem to do anything in view mode.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. For interactive maps the `leaflet` package seems to give you more control than `tmap` (at the cost of having to learn additional syntax)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove legend in tmap in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031445/remove-legend-in-tmap-in-r)

Comment: Even though you asked your question first (!), someone else's version of this question already got answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031445/remove-legend-in-tmap-in-r so I've flagged this as a duplicate. The accepted answer there should deal with your issue here.