# Remove legend in tmap in R

Tags: r, tmap

I have a simple question: How does one remove an automatically added legend in tmap in R?

In this case, I want to remove that legend on the right, depicting 'level'.

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
tm_shape(densities$polygons)+
  tm_polygons(col='level', palette='Reds', alpha=0.5, border.col = 'transparent') + 
  tm_legend(show=FALSE)
```

I have also tried:

```
tm_shape(densities$polygons)+
  tm_polygons(col='level', palette='Reds', alpha=0.5, border.col = 'transparent') + 
  tm_layout(legend.show=FALSE)
```

Not sure why but none of these removes the legend. Would appreciate any solutions, thank you!

Comment: I don't know tmap, but since it is related to ggplot, did you try `legend.position="none"`?

Comment: Just tried:
tm_shape(densities$polygons)+
  tm_polygons(col='level', palette='Reds', alpha=0.5, border.col = 'transparent') + 
  tm_view(view.legend.position="none")

Doesn't work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tmap)

tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(densities$polygons) +
  tm_polygons(col = "plz", legend.show = FALSE)
```

`tm_layout()` doesn't work in your case because you are in `view`-mode. Several other options for the legend in view mode won't work with tm_layout either, such as `legend.position =` (there is `tm_view()` for this)

If you switch to `tmap_mode("plot")` your code will work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `tm_polygons` use `tm_fill(title = "")` to remove the legend title. This worked for me.